# How to get large thumbnails in hosted Explorer browser control?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-shell, windows-explorer, windows-api-code-pack

Using the good old [Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) to host an Explorer view inside my WinForms application, I want to programmatically force a **large thumbnail** view (Windows 8) like this:

[image]

*(Large thumbnails, option checked)*

Unfortunately, no matter which parameter from the [`FOLDERVIEWMODE` enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762510.aspx) I pass to the [`IFolderView::SetCurrentViewMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775618.aspx) method, all I can achieve is this:

[image]

*(Small thumbnails, option not checked)*

**Therefore my question:**

Which method(s) could I possibly use to always force the large thumbnails mode in my hosted Explorer browser control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comes out that on *my* system the solution was to apply the following settings:

- [View mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifolderview-setcurrentviewmode) = **Icon**
- [Thumbnail size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifolderview2-setviewmodeandiconsize) = **96**

(With the Windows API Code Pack wrappers, I had to do two function calls; in real-life, one call to the [`IFolderView2::SetViewModeAndIconSize` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifolderview2-setviewmodeandiconsize) would be sufficient).

After setting these values, the checkbox in my 2nd screenshot automatically was checked.

I'll assume that this may behave different on different systems. I'll still have to do some testing on this.

Comment: It works, but forces the setting. I would like to set as default, but let user override it, like IShellFolder2::GetViewMode(), do you know how to do that?